# conformsToProtocol will not compile with custom Protocol

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I want to check that a `UIViewController` conforms to a protocol of my own creation:

```
import UIKit

protocol myProtocol {
    func myfunc()
}

class vc : UIViewController {

}

extension vc : myProtocol {
    func myfunc() {
        //My implementation for this class
    }
}

//Not allowed
let result = vc.conformsToProtocol(myProtocol)

//Allowed
let appleResult = vc.conformsToProtocol(UITableViewDelegate)
```

However I get the following error :

`Cannot convert value of type '(myprotocol).Protocol' (aka 'myprotocol.Protocol') to expected argument type 'Protocol'`

[image: Playground]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `@objc protocol myProtocol {
    func myfunc()
}`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Swift, the better solution is `is`:

```
let result = vc is MyProtocol
```

or `as?`:

```
if let myVC = vc as? MyProtocol { ... then use myVC that way ... }
```

But to use `conformsToProtocol`, you must mark the protocol `@objc`:

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {
    func myfunc()
}
```

(Note that classes and protocols should always start with a capital.)

Comment: Does any one know the reason why this occurs with .conforms(to: protocol) ?

Comment: @hoboBob Because `conforms(to:)` (the new name for this method) requires an object of type `Protocol`. This is an ObjC type (it's imported from the objc runtime), so to use it, `MyProtocol` needs to be an `@objc` protocol. `conforms(to:)` is not a Swift method; it's part of the ObjC runtime. The Swift version equivalent is built into the language: `is`.

Comment: Thanks man I've been jumping back to this post every now and then when I bump into this.